# Filament : How to edit records from other model

Tags: laravel-filament

I'm trying to solve this problem: I have a table offers. every time after creating a new offer, 6 default articles are copied to the offerposts table and the offer_id key is added to them. consequently, I need to be able to edit all offer posts that belong to a specific offer in the offer editing. I have the records loaded, but as soon as I draw them through Tabs, the values ​​are not inserted into the text field but are above it and therefore I cannot edit it. The goal is that in a specific price offer, in addition to the offer fields, I can also edit the text of all offerposts that have the same offer_id as the offer. Thanks in advance for your help

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Admin\Resources;

use App\Filament\Admin\Resources\OfferResource\Pages;
use App\Filament\Admin\Resources\OfferResource\RelationManagers;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Fieldset;
use App\Models\Offer;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Language;
use Filament\Forms;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Filament\Forms\Components\MarkdownEditor;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Section;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\OfferPost;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Tabs;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Textarea;
use Filament\Tables\Actions\EditAction;
use Filament\Forms\Components\ViewField;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class OfferResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Offer::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-shopping-bag';




    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {

        $currentOffer = $form->getRecord();
        //$offerPosts = OfferPost::where('offer_id', $currentOffer->id);
        $offerPosts = OfferPost::where('offer_id', $currentOffer->id)->get();

        $currentId = 5;

        return $form
            ->schema([
                Section::make('Basic informations')
                ->description('Please fill all basic informations about offer')
                ->schema([
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                    ->required()
                    ->autofocus()
                    ->suffix('id'),
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('project')
                    ->required(),
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('deal_id'),
                    Forms\Components\Select::make('partner_id')
                    ->options(Customer::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                    ->preload()
                    ->searchable()
                    ->label(__('Partner')),
                    Forms\Components\Select::make('lang_id')
                    ->options(Language::all()->pluck('name', 'id'))
                    ->preload()
                    ->default(Language::first()->id)
                    ->label(__('Language')),
                    Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('expiration')
                    ->required()
                    ->firstDayOfWeek(1)
                    ->default(Carbon::now()->addDays(15)->format('Y-m-d')),
                    Forms\Components\MarkdownEditor::make('description')
                    ->columnSpanFull(),

                    Fieldset::make('Location')
                        ->schema([
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('address')
                            ->required(),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('city')
                            ->required(),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('zipcode')
                            ->required(),
                        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('state')
                            ->required(),
                    ]),
                    Fieldset::make('Prices')
                        ->schema([
                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('extra_work_price')
                                ->numeric(),
                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('total_price')
                            ->default(0)
                                ->readonly(),
                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('total_price2')
                                ->default(0)
                                ->readonly(),
                    ])->columns(3),
                ])->columns(3),

                Section::make('General texts')
                    ->schema([
                        Tabs::make('Tabs')
                        ->tabs(function() use ($offerPosts) {
                            foreach ($offerPosts as $offerPost) {
                                $body = $offerPost->body;
                                $name = $offerPost->name;

                                $tabs[] = Tabs\Tab::make($name)
                                    ->schema([
                                        Forms\Components\MarkdownEditor::make($body)
                                       
                                    ]);
                            }

                            return $tabs;
                        })

                    ]),

            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('partner.name')
                    ->numeric()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('lang.name')
                    ->numeric()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('extra_work_price')
                    ->numeric()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('total_price')
                    ->numeric()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('total_price2')
                    ->numeric()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('expiration')
                    ->date()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('created_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('updated_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListOffers::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateOffer::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditOffer::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }

}
```

what i bacame is :
[image]

for me, the text is displayed above the MarkDownEditor, and I can't edit it